# How to add constant value to axis 1 (only) of 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 2D array, such as

```
a = array([[0,1],[10,12]])
```

Is there a simple and fast (for huge arrays) way to create a new 2D array `aplus1` which adds a constant only to the 2nd axis, while keeping the 1st axis as it is? I thus wish to obtain (for constant = 1)

```
array([[0,1],[11,13]])
```

I was hoping that `aplus1 = np.add(a,1,axis=1)` would be available, but `np.add` has no option `axis=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can do this by indexing as:

```
a[row_index, :] += constant_value
```

So, for modifying `a`:

```
a[1, :] += 1             # [[ 0  1] [11 13]]
```

or if you need a new array, you can copy `a` at first. So, e.g., if `row_index = 1` and `constant_value = 2`:

```
b = np.copy(a)
b[1, :] += 2             # [[ 0  1] [12 14]]
```